# BigCommerce cart redirect url

Tags: bigcommerce

I used BigCommerce v3 API to create cart redirect url
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/cart/server-to-server-cart/create-redirect-url
Got 2 links (cart_url and checkout_url). When I tried to use cart link I got cart page with empty cart and error message "Your cart couldn't be retrieved. Please click here to continue shopping."
Has anyone faced the same?

```
import json
import requests

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-Auth-Client': '***',
  'X-Auth-Token': '***'
}
store = '***'
cart_uuid = '********-****-****-****-************'
url = 'https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{}/v3/carts/{}/redirect_urls'.format(store, cart_uuid)

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
response_dict = json.loads(r.text)
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Shared. But I got those links. The problem is they don't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53279257/bigcommerce-cart-redirect-url-not-working
Are you trying to create a redirect URL using a cart created on the storefront? You are currently not able to since they are tied to a shoppers session. See this Stack Overflow answer above and the Server to Server Cart Redirect URLs which also mention this behavior. https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api/cart/postcartscartidredirecturls

Comment: Yes, this cart was created by normal user behavior (adding product). Thanks a lot for these links - this might work

Answer (score 0):

To make a cart redirect URL there are two ways:

1. [While creating the cart:](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api/cart/postcartscartidredirecturls)
   `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{$$.env.store_hash}/v3/carts?include=redirect_urls`
   Pass in `redirect_urls` as the include.
2. [After the cart is created:](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api/cart/postcarts)
   `https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{$$.env.store_hash}/v3/carts/{cartId}/redirect_urls`
   Use `redirect_urls` as part of the request url, along with the `cartId`.

Make sure to replace cartId with the id that comes back in the response for /POST Cart. Also make sure the cart is still valid by doing a [/GET request](https://developer-beta.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-cart-api/cart/getcartscartid) for the cart id.

Carts are only valid for 30 days.